# For Loop Continue For

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to filter items listed in my listview. Every items on listview should be checked if it already exist to my database. And Those that are not in database, will be INSERTED.

This the codes that I tried.

```
Sub Save()
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListViewSelectedOffice.Items
        CONNECTION.Close()
        CONNECTION.Open()
        Query = "SELECT * FROM table_documentdestinationlog WHERE LogNo = '" & Me.TextBoxLogNo.Text & "' AND OfficeDestination = '" & item.SubItems(1).Text & "'"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(Query, CONNECTION)
        Reader = comm.ExecuteReader
        If Reader.HasRows = True Then
            Continue For
        End If
        'Do Something
        CONNECTION.Close()
        CONNECTION.Open()
        Query = "INSERT INTO table_documentdestinationlog (LogNo, OfficeDestination, Status) VALUES (@logno, @officeD, 'Pending')"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(Query.ToString, CONNECTION)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logno", LabelLogNo.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@officeD", item.SubItems(1).Text)
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next item
```

I also Tried

```
 Sub SaveToDestinationLog1()
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListViewSelectedOffice.Items
            CONNECTION.Close()
            CONNECTION.Open()
            Query = "SELECT * FROM table_documentdestinationlog WHERE LogNo = '" & Me.TextBoxLogNo.Text & "' AND OfficeDestination = '" & item.SubItems(1).Text & "'"
            comm = New MySqlCommand(Query, CONNECTION)
            Reader = comm.ExecuteReader
            If Reader.HasRows = True Then
                Continue For

            Else
                GoTo LINE1
            End If

LINE1:
            'Do Something
            CONNECTION.Close()
            CONNECTION.Open()
            Query = "INSERT INTO table_documentdestinationlog (LogNo, OfficeDestination, Status) VALUES (@logno, @officeD, 'Pending')"
            comm = New MySqlCommand(Query.ToString, CONNECTION)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logno", LabelLogNo.Text)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@officeD", item.SubItems(1).Text)
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next item
    End Sub
```

Still did not get the result I want.

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: I recommend you find a way to write the code without any `GoTo` statements, as it is bad practice and causes all kinds of problems (like this) and confusion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Comment: `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` looks like it's VB.NET, not VBA - correct? Please [edit] your post to tag with the appropriate language, VBA and VB.NET are very different. `Continue For` isn't legal in VBA, for example.

Comment: The connection should be as short-lived as reasonably possible (open before the loop, close after the loop), and it should be enclosed in a `Using` block to ensure its `Dispose` method is invoked. Ditto with the `MySqlCommand` and the `Reader` objects... and there should be a `Try/Catch` block too, to prevent any exceptions from bubbling up the call stack from here. Consider implementing this logic outside the UI, too.

Comment: Consider using Dapper.NET (get it from Nuget package manager) instead of raw ADO.NET and dealing with parameters and datareaders; it's a game changer, really. (caveat: I use it in C#, unsure what the VB.NET syntax would be for creating the anonymous types representing the parameters)

Comment: The result is that, still all items in listview is saved in the database even if it already exist.

Comment: I tried having try catch on this too, still not working. still save items that is already listed on my database.

Comment: What is this "`CONNECTION.Close()
        CONNECTION.Open()`"? Connections should be created and disposed in the method where they are used.

Comment: Please, no `GoTo`. This is known as spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

When logic becomes hard to follow and execution "needs" to start jumping up and down, it's time to restructure things a bit.

Extract the code into smaller, more specialized functions to make your `Save` procedure read more clearly:

```
Private Sub Save()
    Dim LogID As String = Me.TextBoxLogNo.Text
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListViewSelectedOffice.Items
        Dim OfficeDest As String = item.SubItems(1).Text
        If IsNewEntry(LogID, OfficeDest) Then
            InsertNewPendingEntry(LogID, OfficeDest)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now, you need an `IsNewEntry` function that returns `True` when the entry should be inserted, or `False` if it already exists. Why are you concatenating user inputs into the WHERE clause here though? That creates an unnecessary [SQL injection vulnerability](https://xkcd.com/327/) that you are securely avoiding a few lines later by using formal parameters: do this everywhere!

Then you need an `InsertNewPendingEntry` method that actually performs the insert operation - that would be what you have under that `LINE1:` label.

Consider making the connection local to the `Save` method (and pass it as a parameter to `IsNewEntry` and `InsertNewPendingEntry` methods), enclosed in a `Using` block to ensure proper disposal; there is no need to ever explicitly `Close` a connection when you are properly disposing it. My rule of thumb is that if I don't know when the next command is going to hit a connection, then I need to dispose that connection. In .NET any type that implements `IDisposable` *should* have its `Dispose` method invoked, and the simplest way to do this is to leverage `Using` blocks.

`Try/Catch` blocks would also be warranted, because many things can go wrong with a database connection that you cannot control.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. But I am fairly new with VB.Net. I really only apply what I know and gradually learn more. Yes I use Try Catch with this code that I have. I just wasn't able to include it in.I really don't know nor understand how to create the IsNewEntry and InsertNewPendingEntry that you mention. What I know is I create subs and call them when I need to execute the code inside the sub. is it the same as function?

Comment: Would you please paste the codes here for creating the IsNewEntry and InsertNewPendingEntry function.

Comment: It's your own code, pulled into their own functions; `IsNewEntry` encapsulates the "select records matching the criteria, return true if there are no rows" logic, and `InsertNewPendingEntry` encapsulates the "perform the actual insert" logic.

Comment: @AyeRich verify that the reader actually has no rows, use breakpoints and step-through to debug, and I'd suggest adding a timestamp column in the table to be more easily able to see what gets inserted when.

Comment: @AyeRich I don't know your schema, but if the `LogID` is supposed to be different for each item, then that could be why you're inserting every record, because `Me.TextBoxLogNo.Text` isn't changing between iterations.

Comment: Still getting the same resuts. the flow and logic of the code above is just fairly the same. this code is just shorter. i don't know why everything in listview still saving to my database even if it already exist.

Comment: Good Point. Yes, the LogID is not changing. Only the OfficeDest. As one LogNo can consist of many OfficeDest. So basically, if OfficeDest is not on database, associated with the LogID. then it should not save.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `If Reader.HasRows = True` condition and inspect the values you're using as parameters / concatenating into the WHERE clause, then run the same query with the same values directly in the database (in SQL Server Management Studio) and verify you're getting the same result. Make the SELECT query use named parameters, too. If you have multiple environments, verify your connection string is connecting to the expected server & database. I don't think someone that isn't sitting at your computer can really help beyond that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use `Insert Into...Where Not Exists`. Database objects need to be declared, closed and disposed in the method where they are used. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us even if there is an error.

The only thing that changes in the `For` loop is the value of the `@officeD` parameter. So, that and the `.Execute` is the only thing that belongs in the loop. We don't need to recreate the connection or the command. And we don't want to willy nilly open and closed connections.

```
Sub Save()
    Dim Query = "INSERT INTO table_documentdestinationlog (LogNo, OfficeDestination, Status) VALUES (@logno, @officeD, 'Pending') 
                    Where Not Exists(SELECT * FROM table_documentdestinationlog WHERE LogNo = @logno AND OfficeDestination = @officeD)"
    Using CONNECTION As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            comm As New MySqlCommand(Query, CONNECTION)
        comm.Parameters.Add("@logno", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LabelLogNo.Text
        comm.Parameters.Add("@officeD", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
        CONNECTION.Open()
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListViewSelectedOffice.Items
            comm.Parameters("@officeD").Value = item.SubItems(1).Text
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the hassle guys. but this code actually work. I just didn't notice that I was wrong value for the WHERE clause. I didn't notice that I used TextBoxLogNo.text instead of the LabelLogno.text for my WHERE clause. that's why the it's not returning the right value for the reader.hasrows. I put msgbox for every iteration and notice that it's really not returning the value I wanted. so i reviewed my Query and WHERE clause.  Surely all your suggestions was really helpful.

```
Sub Save()
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListViewSelectedOffice.Items
        CONNECTION.Close()
        CONNECTION.Open()
        Query = "SELECT * FROM table_documentdestinationlog WHERE LogNo = '" & Me.TextBoxLogNo.Text & "' AND OfficeDestination = '" & item.SubItems(1).Text & "'"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(Query, CONNECTION)
        Reader = comm.ExecuteReader
        If Reader.HasRows = True Then
            Continue For
        End If
        'Do Something
        CONNECTION.Close()
        CONNECTION.Open()
        Query = "INSERT INTO table_documentdestinationlog (LogNo, OfficeDestination, Status) VALUES (@logno, @officeD, 'Pending')"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(Query.ToString, CONNECTION)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logno", LabelLogNo.Text)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@officeD", item.SubItems(1).Text)
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next item
```